# Is it possible for admin to have super admin role in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on a multivendor website. i want the admin to have full access to the details updated by users and vendors. Currently the admin can only view bookings and their statuses. Admin cannot change the status. Only vendor can. here is the code

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            Passport::routes();
        }
```

i am confused about the syntax

Comment: There is also `laravel spatie permission` where you can set which permission can access which methods in your controller.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Laravel authorization docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#intercepting-gate-checks) has a section on how to “intercept” a gate check for something like an administrator, who should be able to perform all actions.

```php
Gate::before(function (User $user, string $ability) {
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
});
```